# Java 8 Streams interference inside forEach on a field

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following silly program using java 8 streams:

```
private int biggestInt;

private void run() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

    List<Callable<Integer>> callables = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        callables.add(randomInt());
    }

    try {
        executor.invokeAll(callables)
            .stream()
            .map(future -> {
                    try {
                        return future.get();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                    }
                })
            .forEach(this::compareBiggestInt);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* do nothing */ }
}

private Callable<Integer> randomInt() {
    return () -> {
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return random.nextInt();
    };
}

private void compareBiggestInt(Integer in) {
    if (in > biggestInt)
        biggestInt = in;
}
```

My question is, wether forEach(this::compareBiggestInt) is executed in parallel and thus will introduce a race condition on biggestInt?

If so, how can I avoid this race condition?
Could I for example change the method like the following?

```
private synchronized void compareBiggestInt(Integer in) {[...]}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `forEach` is not executed in parallel. This would break the general contract of how `forEach` is expected to behave when used with `stream()` as opposed to `parallelStream()`, and is not affected by the fact that you've introduced an `ExecutorService`.

The `invokeAll()` actually returns a `List` of `Future` instances that have either *completed or timed out.* So the parallel portion has already completed by the time you interact with your stream.

Answer (score 2):

the `forEach` is not executed in a *parallel* stream. what actually execute async tasks is the `executor`. the `Stream#map` operation will wait until all of the `Future`s done.

**IF** you want an operation is executed in a parallel stream, you should using the [reduction operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) : [Stream#reduce](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). for example:

```
biggestInt = executor.invokeAll(callables)
        .parallelStream()
        .map(...)// same with yours
        .reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Hi holi-java, how are you? Just a detail about wording... Stream.reduce is not mutable reduction​, because the intermediate results are not accumulated in a mutable structure. The mutable reduction operation of streams  is collect.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Hi, I just copy [the documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). I think it is right. you can see it at the description of the `Collector` class.

Comment: But you have linked to the *Reduction* section of the package documentation, which is different from the *Mutable reduction* section following. `reduce` is *Reduction*, `collect` is *Mutable reduction*.

Comment: @Holger hi, the documentation also do that. I just copy and paste it from the [package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). :)

Comment: I don’t know what “the document” is supposed to be. You have linked to the `java.util.stream` package documentation, which describes several different concept. *Reduction* is one of them, which describes that concept and the associated method `reduce`, *Mutable reduction* is another, being described in the subsequent section using the associated method `collect`. The method documentation of `reduce` clearly links to *Reduction*, but of course, if you scroll down to the next section, you will get to *Mutable reduction* but if you *read* these two section, you should notice that it’s new section

Comment: @Holger  I know what we are saying just now from your comments. I have fixed the answer. you are right, the documentation say several things. thanks very much.

Comment: There’s another thing, there’s only `maxBy` requiring a `Comparator` in `BinaryOperator` so the operation has to be `.reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))`, but you can simplify this to `.max(Comparator.naturalOrder())` offered by the Stream API, which will do the same internally.

Comment: @Holger yeah, the answer is simple that I never read the documentation at all just type what I think. thanks again. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 2):

There a few problems here. First:

```
return () -> {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return random.nextInt();
};
```

The execution can be *so fast* (I can easily reproduce) that this would return the same value all the time.

I would suggest you remove that `millis` at least:

```
private static Callable<Integer> randomInt() {
    return () -> {
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println(x);
        return x;
    };
}
```

Or even better use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100)`

I've also changed `nextInt` to return within bounds up to `[0.. 100]` because `nextInt` could return a negative value and imagine you are returning 50 negative values and then your max would be `zero` (default value) of `biggestInt`; which is obviously wrong.

And then your stream is `sequential` and inside each `map` operation you block until that `Future.get` finishes. So your `forEach` is executed by a single thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about Math.random()? Could I also use that in this fast execution context? (I know that this would return a double between 0 and 1, which is fine for the moment)

Comment: @Sven793 you could use `System.nanoTime()` for nano-seconds precisions, which would increase the probability for better random numbers.

Comment: @Sven793 also the correct question, now that you know, that `forEach` is going to be run by a single thread; what would be the result if you add `parallel` to the stream?

Comment: I tried that and it seemed like it executed forEach in parallel. I added two different print statements at the beginning and at the end of compareBiggestInt which then 'showed' the parallel execution.

Comment: @Sven793 you mean you added `parallel` and saw that the stream is executed in parallel? That is pretty much expected. Let me re-phrase what I said: would adding `parallel` display a *different* max value than a sequential stream *for the same data*?

Comment: @Eugene, do note though, that `System.nanoTime()` does not necessarily produce the stamps with actual nanoseconds precision. I remember some Windows machine not having nano-precision clocks, so `nanoTime()` there returns stamps truncated to milli-precision that system clocks support.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov excellent point! I remember myself something like this related, but was not sure... thx for input

Comment: Ahem, don’t forget that these `Callable`s are *supposed* to run in parallel, as they are passed to `invokeAll`. So even with a dead slow machine and a high accuracy timer, several of them could produce the same value when using the system time as seed. So why not use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100)`, which will be even faster than creating a local `Random` instance for each number (since Java 7)…

Comment: @Holger yeah... should have thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `parallel` stream, so your stream is sequential. If you want to be sure that your stream is done sequential add `.sequential()` method to your stream.

From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--):

```
default Stream<E> stream()  
Returns a sequential Stream with this collection as its source.
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are running the streams in parallel (I changed the code to use "parallelStream"), you have to protect all changes to the shared mutable variables.

for example, in code below I'm using "synchronized" in method "compareBiggestInt" to protect all accesses to variable "biggestInt".   (if you remove "synchronized" and run below code you can see that there is indeed a race condition in method "compareBiggestInt")

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class ParallelStreamExample  {

    private volatile int biggestInt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParallelStreamExample parallelStreamExample = new ParallelStreamExample();
        parallelStreamExample.doTheWork();
    }



    private void doTheWork() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

        List<Callable<Integer>> callables = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            callables.add(randomInt());
        }

        try {
            executor.invokeAll(callables)
                    .parallelStream()
                    .map(future -> {
                        try {
                            return future.get();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                        }
                    })
                    .forEach(this::compareBiggestInt);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* do nothing */ }
    }

    private Callable<Integer> randomInt() {
        return () -> {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.nextInt(10);
        };
    }

    private synchronized void compareBiggestInt(Integer in)  {
        System.out.println("in:" + in + " - current biggestint = " + biggestInt);
        if (in > biggestInt) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            biggestInt = in;
        }
        System.out.println("in:" + in + " - current biggestint = " + biggestInt);
    }
}
```